# Simple Product Attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, simple-product

1. I have a Magento 2.2.1 application. I want to show the product attributes(Size, Color and Brand) below the Product Price for Simple Products. I currently shows at More Information for Simple Products, and it also shows at the desired location for Configured Products, how do i move it below the Product Price or Before the Add to Cart Button for just Simple Products.

[image]

2. How do I show the attributes(Color, Size or Brand) on the Products Page two?

[image]

Comment: Are you a magento developer?

Comment: Yes I am a developer, but new to Magento.

Comment: Have you researched? Have you learned the basics?

Comment: Yes I have, I have  tried this ans soo many other solutions              
 echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getColor(), 'color'));